# Как передать в Web API из приложения C# класс, содержащий строки и массив байтов?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Контроллер Web API `Post([FromBody]MyClass value)` принимает на вход класс например такого вида:

```
MyClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public byte[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

Какими средствами из клиентского приложения C# можно отправить такую же структуру?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю посмотреть в сторону [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).
Так же вы не уточнили принимаемый `ContentType`, поэтому я предлагаю использовать `json` и серилизовать отправляемый объект с помощью [`Newtonsoft.JSON`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

В итоге можно будет отправлять запрос и получать ответ так:

```
public async Task<WebApiResponse> PostAsync(string address, object data)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(dataString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(address, httpContent);

            var responseDataString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var webApiResponse = new WebApiResponse(response.StatusCode, responseDataString);

            return webApiResponse;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        const HttpStatusCode errorStatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)599;
        var webApiResponse = new WebApiResponse(errorStatusCode, ex.Message);

        return webApiResponse;
    }
}
```

где `WebApiResponse` - класс, который содержит в себе полученный ответ:

```
public class WebApiResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccessful => (int)StatusCode >= 200 && (int)StatusCode <= 399;

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }

    public string ResponseDataString { get; }


    public WebApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string responseDataString)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        ResponseDataString = responseDataString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не уточнил про ContentType, потому что в данном случае ничего про него не знаю. Я просто создал проект MVC Web API и объявил там вышеупомянутый класс со строкой и массивом байтов. Если бы в классе были только строковые свойства, отправить данные из клиента можно было бы через WebClient и NameValueCollection. При этом никакого преобразования к JSON не происходит явно в коде. Думал что есть какой-то штатный способ в .Net, без привлечения сторонних библиотек.